# Handling Connection Errors and Resuming Streaming in GStreamer RTSP Pipeline

Tags: c++, gstreamer, rtsp

I am new to Gstreamer.

I have an RTSP source in my GStreamer pipeline that transmits packages successfully. However, in case of a temporary loss of connection, the pipeline fully stops. I want to implement a solution where, upon detecting an error message, the pipeline continues streaming by feeding it with dummy frames (e.g., using videotestsrc pattern=black) until the connection is restored.

As the official Gstreamer documentation states : "Elements do not have the context required to decide what to do with errors. As such, they should only inform about errors, and stop their processing. In short, an element doesn't know what it is being used for". How can I detect and handle connection errors in GStreamer? Is there a way to modify the pipeline to keep it active during connection interruptions and resume normal streaming once the connection is reestablished?

Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Here is the high-level overview of what I have done:

I have tried getting a GstMessage using
`gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered()`

Then, if the message states an error, remove *rtspsrc* and replace it with *videotestsrc*.

```
gst_bin_remove(GST_BIN(pipeline), rtspsrc);
gst_bin_add(GST_BIN(pipeline), videotestsrc);
```

However, this approach is clearly wrong as it does not consider connection recover (will have to switch to rtspsrc back again).

One suggestion that might work is to add a probe to rtspsrc's pad to detect any error. Once the error is detected, somehow try to manipulate the pipeline by replacing videotestsrc.

(My ultimate goal is to have an uninterrupted, concurrent videostream that is not affected by accidental errors that may terminate the whole pipeline).

Comment: I believe that the proper way to handle such cases, since the rtspsrc will send an EOS signal down the pipeline, is to have a bus callback that collects the messages and, in case the source has disconnected (or fails for any reason), sets the pipeline to the NULL state, reconnects the rtspsrc, and then restores the PLAY state. This discussion might be helpful [Resuming rtsp stream on EOS](https://gstreamer-devel.narkive.com/OgS3mE8V/resuming-rtsp-stream-on-receiving-eos-signal-on-message-bus-using-re-connection-timer#post5)